# Sending multipart POST data without external libraries

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, apache-httpclient-4.x

My Android app architecture is based on `DefaultHttpClient`. About 2 days ago, I header they're improving `HttpURLConnection` and I was about to change the whole architecture to work with it, but it seemed like too much code rewriting, so I sticked to `DefaultHttpClient`.

Now I'm having to upload a `multipart` entity and I have been reading about adding an external library called `mime` from `Apache`, which  happens to be **deprecated**.

My question would be, is there a way to send `multipart` entity using the `Android` or `Java` `SDK`? Cause if there isn't then I suppose I'm gonna change it all to `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: Have a look at [DavidWebb and alternatives](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/#background). I'm sure you'll find something without writing from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

You could try out some classes that I wrote for my projects. The multipart form class is a pretty trivial implementation, but it should be easily hackable to accommodate sending arrays of data or whatever you need.

```
/**
 * Used to provide an interface for sending post data of various types.
 */
public interface PostData {
    /**
     * Add the specified field to the post data.
     *
     * @param name The name or title of the field.
     * @param value The value of the field.
     * @return This object (for streamed programming)
     */
    public PostData addField(String name, String value);
    /**
     * End the data.
     */
    public PostData end();

    public String getContentType();
    public String toString();
    public int getLength();
}


/**
 * Generate a multi-part form to post data.
 */
public static class MultiPartForm implements PostData {
    private final static String boundary = "AaBbC0xQrpqqqqqqqq";
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public PostData addField(String name, String value) {
        sb.append("--")
            .append(boundary)
            .append("\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name='")
            .append(name)
            .append("'\n\n")
            .append(value)
            .append("\n");
        return this;
    }

    public PostData end() {
        sb.append("--").append(boundary).append("--");
        return this;
    }

    public final String getContentType() {
        return "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return sb.length();
    }
}


/**
 * Creates URL encoded data.
 * Does not include the question mark at the beginning of the string.
 */
public static class UrlEncodedData implements PostData {
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public PostData addField(String name, String value) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append("&");
        }
        try {
            sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8"))
                .append("=")
                .append(URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
        // Shouldn't ever happen.
        } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {}
        return this;
    }

    public PostData end() {
        return this;
    }

    public final String getContentType() {
        return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    }

    public String toString() {
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return sb.length();
    }
}
```

Along with these, I also created a method to make retrieving data more simple as well. I use HttpURLConnection with this method, but it should be pretty simple to get the gist of how to do the same thing with the DefaultHttpClient. Note that it is synchronous, so you will have to call it in another thread:

```
/**
 * Loads a specified URL with the params incoded in the post.
 * 
 * @throws Exception For numerous reasons.
 * @param url The base URL to connect to.
 * @param data A PostData object to fetch. Specifiy null for a GET request.
 * @return The result.
 */
public static String loadUrl(final String url, final PostData data)
        throws Exception {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();

        if (data != null) {
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");;
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", data.getContentType());
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                Integer.toString(data.getLength()));
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
                urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(data.toString());
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

            urlConnection.connect();
        }

        br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
    } finally {
        try { urlConnection.disconnect(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        try { br.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Usage is quite trivial:

```
Utils.loadUrl("someApi.com/foobar/"
    new Utils.MultiPartForm()
        .addField("first_name", "John")
        .addField("last_name", "Doe")
        .end());
```